# PHP - Problemas al cargar datos en modal Bootstrap

Tags: php, crud

Estoy realizando un CRUD, pero en la parte de actualizar me está dando guerra.
Estoy usando un modal, que es el siguiente:

```html
<h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Actualizar Información</h5>
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
</button>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
    <form id="frmactualiza">
        <input type="text"  name="id_usuario" id="id_usuario">
        <label>Nombre Completo</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="nombrejU" id="nombrejU">
        <label>Categoria : </label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="niveljU" value="1">
        <label>Administrador</label>
        <br><input type="radio" name="niveljU" value="2">
        <label>Maestro</label><br>
        <input type="radio" name="niveljU" value="3">
        <label>Estudiante</label>
        <br><br><label>Direccion</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="direccionjU" id="direccionjU">
        <label>Telefono</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="telefonojU" id="telefonojU">
        <label>Celular</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="celularjU" id="celularjU">
        <label>Correo</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="correojU" id="correojU">
        <label>Contraseña</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" name="clavejU" id="clavejU">
    </form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-raised btn-warning" id="btnactualizar">Actualizar</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Luego uso este método para obtener los datos:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function obtenDatos(idUsuario){
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      data: "idUsuario=" + idUsuario,
      url: "php/obtenerRegistro.php",
      success: function(r){
        datos = jQuery.parseJSON(r);

        $('#id_usuario').val(datos['id_usuario']);
        $('#clavejU').val(datos['clavejU']);
        $('#niveljU').val(datos['niveljU']);
        $('#nombrejU').val(datos['nombrejU']);
        $('#direccionjU').val(datos['direccionjU']);
        $('#telefonojU').val(datos['telefonojU']);
        $('#celularjU').val(datos['celularjU']);
        $('#correojU').val(datos['correojU']);
      }
    });
  }
```

El envio de la variable esta aqui:

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $ver[0]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $ver[1]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $ver[2]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $ver[3]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $ver[4]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $ver[5]; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $ver[6]; ?></td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">
        <span class="btn btn-raised btn-warning btn-xs" onclick="obtenDatos('<?php echo $ver[0]; ?>')" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#updatemodal">
        <span class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></span> Editar</span>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align: center;">
        <span class="btn btn-raised btn-danger btn-xs" 
            onclick="elimina('<?php echo $ver[0]; ?>')">
        <span class="fa fa-trash"></span> Eliminar</span>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Y la actualizacion:

```
<?php
require_once "conexion.php";
$conexion        = conexion();
$id              = $_POST['id_usuario'];
$nombre_completo = $_POST['nombrejU'];
$nivel           = $_POST['niveljU'];
$direccion       = $_POST['direccionjU'];
$telefono        = $_POST['telefonojU'];
$celular         = $_POST['celularjU'];
$correo          = $_POST['correojU'];
$clave           = $_POST['clavejU'];

$sql = "CALL sp_actualizar_datos('$id','$clave','$nombre_completo','$nivel','$direccion','$telefono','$celular','$correo')";

echo mysqli_query($conexion, $sql);
?>
```

El problema es que al darle editar me carga el model pero con los campos vacios, uso la siguiente plantilla:

[Plantilla GitHub Facultad Autodidacta](https://www.youtube.com/redirect?redir_token=qjlexTCMuXkF_qZi4XY4-il936R8MTUyNDU5ODYxMUAxNTI0NTEyMjEx&event=video_description&v=WDR9zTBNLwg&q=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2Ffacultadautodidacta%2FstoresConPhp)

Gracias de antemano por su valiosa ayuda.

Comment: Dennis, bienvenido a la comunidad de Stack Overflow :)

Answer (score 1):

El error debe estar en el la línea

```
echo mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
```

No puedes hacer echo directamente sobre lo devuelto por *mysqli_query*. Primero tienes que convertir los datos a un array y de ahí a JSON.

```
$result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
$json = json_encode(mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC));
$error = json_last_error();

header('Content-type: text/javascript');

if ( !$error ) {
    echo $json;
} else {
    echo "{'error':$error}";
}
```

Aunque te convendría más usar un *while* y armar un array únicamente con los datos que necesites y recién ahí hacer la conversión a JSON porque dependiendo del contenido de la tabla y la codificación de la misma *json_encode* puede fallar.

---

Edición: Agregado control de error de codificación y envío de headers correctos

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente sea por la forma en la que accedes a los atributos de un objeto (JSON)

```
datos['id_usuario'];
```

intenta de la siguiente forma:

```
datos.id_usuario;
```